# Push Upgrade Failure - deployment failed while trying to push upgrades to orgs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, push

Hi folks we have a lightning component pack on App Exchange. Which includes the one lightning page in the managed package. We want to send the latest version push to upgrade to our customers but it gives the Deploy Error.

**Error**:
flexipages/Demo_Page.flexipage. In Lightning component testComponent, property testField has an invalid value testValue.

We didn't make any change in the lightning component design property but still getting this error.

**Workaround**
If we upgrade the customer through app exchange or direct Install URL then it is successfully installed and upgraded into customer orgs.

Comment: Is the behavior the same on all subscribers (that is, do you have a 100% failure rate on push upgrades)? Does it always succeed on an install-URL upgrade when it previously failed on a push upgrade?

Comment: Yes, @david right now I have tried with 2,4 production and sandbox org.  it fails for all org Yes it is successfully upgraded with install URL  but failed with push upgrade

Comment: I would recommend you open a case - this sounds like something that support should investigate.

Comment: Yes David I opened the case let see what comes out. thanks